# Unity how to override unity components?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just want to improve myselft about editor scripting. I saw same plugins to handle unity components like "Transform". And then I google it. I found some answers and ways to do that. But I want to handle settings button on the top right.

I found this link => [Extending (instead of replacing) built-in Inspectors](https://forum.unity.com/threads/extending-instead-of-replacing-built-in-inspectors.407612/)

[image: Button to handle]

I want to handle this button to add some settings stuff

Comment: have a look at [ContextMenu](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenu.html)

Comment: Omg thanks dude. You are a life saver..

Comment: ;) no problem. Cool find however! This Transform looks very interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context Menu Attribute solved my problem.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenu.html